# Doctrine/MongoDB: Use key-value pairs instead numeric array

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine ODM with MongoDB. I have a "product model" like this:

```
namespace Cms\Model;

/** @Document(collection="products") */
class Product
{
    /** @Id */
    private $id;

    /** @String */
    private $title;

    /** @String */
    private $description;

    /** @Date */
    private $createdAt;

    /** @EmbedMany(targetDocument="Cms\Model\ProductParam") */
    private $params;

    /** @EmbedOne(targetDocument="Cms\Model\Coordinate") */
    private $coordinate;

    public function  __construct()
    {
        $this->details = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->params = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

My ProductParam model is like this:

```
namespace Cms\Model;

/** @EmbeddedDocument */
class ProductParam
{
    /** @String */
    private $type;

    /** @String */
    private $value;
}
```

When i insert documents with this schema, the result is this:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4d17ac603ffcf6d01300002a"),
   "title": "Peugeot 206 2001-X-Reg, 1.4lx Air-con, 12 months mot, Credit Cards Accepted.",
   "description": "PEUGEOT 206 1.4LX IMMACULATE THROUGHOUT DRIVES ABSOLUTELY SUPERB",
   "params": {
     "0": {
       "type": "carBrand",
       "value": "PEUGEOT"
    },
     "1": {
       "type": "carModel",
       "value": "206 LX"
    }
}
```

But what i need is like this:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4d17ac603ffcf6d01300002a"),
   "title": "Peugeot 206 2001-X-Reg, 1.4lx Air-con, 12 months mot, Credit Cards Accepted.",
   "description": "PEUGEOT 206 1.4LX IMMACULATE THROUGHOUT DRIVES ABSOLUTELY SUPERB",
   "params": {
     carBrand: "PEUGEOT",
     carModel: "206 LX"
   }
}
```

How can i do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you do not use PostLoad, PrePersist etc. as it would be really expensive, instead use `strategy="set"`
E.g:

```
@EmbedMany(targetDocument="Field", strategy="set")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Hash` type, but it only references an associative array, not another object. But you use this in conjunction with `PostLoad` and `PrePersist` events to convert between an object and associative array.